# JHipster Beanstalk deployment issue on AWS

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, jhipster

I created app using jhipster. I created war file using :

```
./mvnw -Pprod package
```

I would like to deploy my WAR file to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I tried to run it but when i run my war file on AWS i get this error : 
[image]

Do i need some additional config to run it ?

Comment: Did you compile it on EB instance? There are some library version differences.